# Using transform function in new Mongo.Collection that uses other collection always returns empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to replicate the behavior shown here :
http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb

I have a Collection called Ensembles that has objetsIds in it. I want to transform those ids so that they become Objets in the doc instead of ids. Both of my Collection are separated into two files, ensembles.js and objets.js. It looks like if it were on the same files it would work but I am having trouble making it work as is.

I've console.logged my doc.objets and it gives me [1,2]. If I do db.objets.find({id:{$in:[1,2]}}) in the mongo db console I get the results as well. But in the code it always returns an empty array as well as when I do just a simple .find({}). If I must subscribe how and where should I do it?

ENSEMBLES.JS

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Objets } from '../api/objets.js';

export const Ensembles = new Mongo.Collection('ensembles', {
    transform: function(doc){
        doc.objetsFull = Objets.find({
            _id : { $in: doc.objets }
        });
        return doc;
    }
});

Ensembles.attachBehaviour('softRemovable');

if (Meteor.isServer) {    
    Meteor.publish('ensembles', function ensemblesPublish() {
        return Ensembles.find({});
    });
    Meteor.methods({
        'ensembles.insert'(ens) {
            Ensembles.schema = new SimpleSchema({
                "Name": { type: String },
                "like": { type: Number, optional: true },
                "addedToMongoAt": { type: Date },
                "objets": { type: [String], optional: true },
                "imagePath" : { type: String, optional:true},
                "likes" : {type : Number, optional:true},
            });
            ens.addedToMongoAt = new Date();
            ens.likes = 0;
            check(ens, Ensembles.schema);            
            return Ensembles.insert(ens);
        },
        'ensembles.remove'(id) {
            Ensembles.softRemove({_id: id});
        },
        'ensembles.update'() {

        }
    });
}
```

OBJETS.JS

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

    export const Objets = new Mongo.Collection('objets');

    if (Meteor.isServer) {

      Meteor.publish('objets', function objetsPublication(skipCount, limit) {
        return Objets.find({}, { limit: 30 });
      });
    }
```